# Passing value between Action through Action Chaining

Tags: java, struts2, action, chaining

I have a Bean like this

```
private String projectName;
private String projectCode;
```

It contains valid getter and setter.

Inside my Action class I am returning this as List and further passing on to JSP to be shown.

```
<select class="ibm-styled" name="selectedProjects" id="selectedProjects" 
        multiple="multiple"   tabindex="1"> 
    <s:iterator value="projectList">
        <option value="<s:property value='projectCode' />">
             <s:property value="projectName"/> 
        </option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

In My Action, I have this `selectedProjects` value and its getter setter defined.

And there I am converting `selectedProjects` that contains `projectCode` part of Bean into `projectName`

And I have setted into a String `selectedProjectName` with valid getter setter

So, Now I have two values in my action class, One set by JSP named `selectedProjects` and another set by me `selectedProjectName`.

```
private String selectedProjects = null;
private String selectedProjectName= null;
```

I tested it, I am able to print them both from action class on console. Now comes the real problem....I need to call another Action via action chaining and pass both parameters their

```
<action name="reports" class="com.ibm.succession.tool.actions.Reports" method="generateReport">
            <result name="tsrep">/TenuredSummary.jsp</result>
            <result name="strprep" type="chain">
                <param name="actionName">displaySkillReport</param>
                <param name="selectedProjects">${selectedProjects}</param>
                <param name="selectedProjectName">${selectedProjectName}</param>
            </result>   
        </action>
```

And its action like this

```
<action name="displaySkillReport"  class="com.ibm.succession.tool.actions.SkillTypeReportAction">
            <result name="success">/skillTypeResoucePlan.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Now, In `SkillTypeReportAction` I have again both two values with getter and setters

```
private String selectedProjects = null;
    private String selectedProjectName= null;
```

But When I am trying to use it there.....`selectedProjectName` is coming blank but the other one is working fine.

Can someone shed some light on this, Let me know if need any further details.

Comment: How could it coming blank or other one is working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters between actions than instead of `type=chain` you should use `<result type="redirectAction">`

```
   <action name="reports" class="com.ibm.succession.tool.actions.Reports" method="generateReport">
        <result name="tsrep">/TenuredSummary.jsp</result>
        <result name="strprep" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">displaySkillReport</param>
            <param name="selectedProjects">${selectedProjects}</param>
            <param name="selectedProjectName">${selectedProjectName}</param>
        </result>   
    </action>
```

**for Struts 2.2**

```
 <result type="redirectAction">
```

**for Struts 2.0**

```
 <result type="redirect-action">
```

Also comment if this does not work for you.